# Need help downloading spreadsheet from Drive using Drive SDK

Tags: drupal, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use Google Drive in my Drupal application.

I need to open a spreadsheet (already in Drive account) in this application.

Here is how I am setting this up:

1.) I build the service by calling the buildService function (code provided)

```
function buildService(){
  $key=
 file_get_contents(TRUE_PATH.'9e01fd1414aa082fadeec316161eb7028558fbdeprivatekey.p12');
  $auth = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    //array(DRIVE_SCOPE),
  $key);
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setUseObjects(true);
  $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
  return new Google_DriveService($client);
}
```

2.) on the other side, I grab the return: $service = buildService();

How would I get my spreadsheet from Drive after building the service? I know the url for the spreadsheet, but I don't know the fileId (not sure where to find this).

I apologize if this is a stupid question. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url of your spreadsheet should look like the following:

```
https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=<DOCUMENT_ID>#gid=0
```

Essentially, the value of the `key` query parameter is the file id that can be used with the Drive API.